# Comparar 2 array diferentes tipo

Tags: php, array

Tengo a `$datos[]` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Nro1] => 6
            [Nro2] => 8
            [Nro3] => 15
            [Nro4] => 23
            [Nro5] => 30
            [Nro6] => 40
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [Nro1] => 4
        [Nro2] => 8
        [Nro3] => 14
        [Nro4] => 17
        [Nro5] => 21
        [Nro6] => 36
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Nro1] => 2
        [Nro2] => 9
        [Nro3] => 20
        [Nro4] => 25
        [Nro5] => 32
        [Nro6] => 36
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Nro1] => 4
        [Nro2] => 21
        [Nro3] => 22
        [Nro4] => 23
        [Nro5] => 32
        [Nro6] => 35
```

y tengo a `$numeros`:

```
$numeros = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,30,23,45,21)
```

y lo que necesito es comparar si `$datos` contiene lo que `$numeros` y si es así cuantas veces se repite ese numero en `$datos`, $datos esta discriminado por periodos y por cada 6 números por eso no lo metí en un vector con `array_walk_recursive`, si lo meto a un vector los períodos desaparecen poniéndolos todos juntos.
Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado y qué dificultades tienes?

Comment: Hola A. Cedano no logro comparar el array asociativo $datos con el array $numeros sin usar :
 
array_walk_recursive($datos, function($datos) use (&$vector) {

Comment: Necesito saber si X número de cada subarray del array $datos aparece segun el array $numeros y en que posición. He usado array_unique o intersec pero para usarlos debo tener 2 array del mismo tipo y como verá los array son diferentes . Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, explicado de manera simple, quieres saber cuántas ocurrencias de los valores de `$datos` se encuentran en números.

Si es eso, entonces puedes lograrlo con **[`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-walk-recursive.php)** . En el código crearemos un nuevo array `$r` con la cantidad de veces que cada valor de `$datos` está en `$numeros`.

Ejemplo:

```
$datos=array(
    array 
        (
             "Nro1" => 4,
             "Nro2" => 8,
             "Nro3" => 15,
             "Nro4" => 23,
             "Nro5" => 30,
             "Nro6" => 40
         ),
    array
        (
            "Nro1" => 6,
            "Nro2" => 8,
            "Nro3" => 14,
            "Nro4" => 17,
            "Nro5" => 21,
            "Nro6" => 36
          ),

    array
        (
            "Nro1" => 2,
            "Nro2" => 9,
            "Nro3" => 20,
            "Nro4" => 25,
            "Nro5" => 32,
            "Nro6" => 36
        ),

    array
        (
            "Nro1" => 4,
            "Nro2" => 21,
            "Nro3" => 22,
            "Nro4" => 23,
            "Nro5" => 32,
            "Nro6" => 35
    )    
);

$numeros = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,30,23,45,21);

#Array para los resultados
$r=array();

array_walk_recursive($datos, function ($v) use (&$r,$numeros) {
    #Verificamos si el valor está en $numeros
    if (in_array($v,$numeros)) { 
        #Si está incrementamos en uno usando su clave
        $r[$v] = (!empty($r[$v]) ? $r[$v] : 0) + 1; 
    }
});

print_r($r);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [4] => 2
    [23] => 2
    [30] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [21] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [9] => 1
)
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias A. Cedano. Excelente!